# What is the PE in 4P+PE connector mean?

Tags: connector, wiring, actuator

I'm wiring a valve actuator to a connector for quick-disconnect purposes. The actuator has five wires so I thought of getting a connector that says 4p+PE, however I was told that 5p was needed.

I'm confused because I thought the 5th pin on the 4p+PE connector (the PE, I'm guessing) is where I can wire in the ground wire from the actuator. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: PE = protective earth. Is it yellow and green?

Comment: The wires on the actuator is Rd Bk Bl Yw Wt. Im not really confused about the actual actuator since I have the spec sheet

Comment: Which country are you located in and/or the parts intended for?

Comment: Is one of the wires a protective earth?

Comment: I am in Canada. And I dont think any of the wires is protective earth. Here is the wiring diagram: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81rkv7YiJRL._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: There is no PE in your wiring diagrams so it is unknown why you bought a connector with 4+PE, and we don't know what connector you bought either. So please edit it the connector make and model so maybe manufacturer data explains what it means to have 4+PE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @winny said, PE stands for Protective Earth, the ground path for fault currents.  Since it is specifically for safety, I don't recommend wiring a power or signal ground to it; get a connector with the correct number of power/signal contacts and connect the PE contact in accordance with the actuator's spec sheet or leave it floating if the spec sheet doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: So to clarify, equipment ground is separate to PE?

Comment: It depends on what they mean by "ground".  There's signal ground, power ground, chassis ground, etc.  Some or all of them may be connected together.  Chassis ground could be considered PE or not; only the datasheet will tell you for sure.

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that all ground can be connected together, as they are all ground anyway. Thank you!